# Play the second track while previous one is stopping (variable code in JS?!)

Tags: javascript

I have a couple tracks that is programmed by JavaScript.
Just One problem that I need to fix and this is
when I play one track is working fine and then when I want to play the other track.
I want to stoped the first one and then play the other one.

```js
const audioPlayers = document.querySelectorAll(".audio-player");

audioPlayers.forEach((audioPlayer) => {
  const audioUrl = audioPlayer.dataset.url;
  const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
  .
  .
  .audio.onplay = () => audioPlayer.classList.add("playing");
    audio.onpause = () => audioPlayer.classList.remove("playing");
    audio.onloadeddata = () => audioPlayer.classList.remove("loading");
    // audio.ondurationchange = showTimeDuration;
    audio.onended = () => (audio.currentTime = 0);
    audio.ontimeupdate = () => {
      const { currentTime } = audio;
      const currentTimeDisplay = formatTimeToDisplay(currentTime);
      updateCurrentTimeDisplay(currentTimeDisplay);
      updateCurrentPercent();
      if (currentTime === 0) {
        showTimeDuration();
      }
    };
  }

  start();
});
```

```html
<div class="audio-player" data-url="sound/1.mp3" dir="ltr">
  <div class="player">
    <button type="button" class="btn-play">
      <span class="material-icons icon-play">play_arrow</span>
      <span class="material-icons icon-pause">pause</span>
      <span class="material-icons icon-loop">loop</span>
      <span class="material-icons icon-error">error_outline</span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:java] tag on your JavaScript questions: they are unrelated languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to stop the current audio playing and play new audio data. How about the solution below: Just call the `stopAllAudio()` function before playing the next audio and all audio playing prior should stop.

```js
function stopAllAudio() {
  var sounds = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  for (i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) sounds[i].pause();
};
```

Comment: Hi, Added to my JS, but it's not working :(